# CROSS APPLY too slow for running total - TSQL

Tags: performance, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, cross-apply

Please see my code below as it is running too slowly with the CROSS APPLY.

How can I remove the CROSS APPLY and add something else that will run faster?
Please note I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

```
;WITH MyCTE AS
(
   SELECT 
      R.NetWinCURRENCYValue AS NetWin
     ,dD.[Date]             AS TheDay
   FROM   
      dimPlayer AS P
   JOIN 
      dbo.factRevenue AS R ON P.playerKey = R.playerKey
   JOIN 
      dbo.vw_Date AS dD ON Dd.dateKey = R.dateKey
   WHERE    
      P.CustomerID   = 12345)
SELECT 
     A.TheDay               AS [Date]
    ,ISNULL(A.NetWin, 0)    AS NetWin
    ,rt.runningTotal        AS CumulativeNetWin
FROM MyCTE AS A
CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUM(NetWin) AS runningTotal 
                  FROM MyCTE WHERE TheDay <= A.TheDay) AS rt
ORDER BY A.TheDay
```

Comment: check this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sqlserver/13744550#13744550

Comment: Have you tried using a LEFT JOIN instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (NetWin money, TheDay datetime)
insert into #temp 
SELECT 
      R.NetWinCURRENCYValue AS NetWin
     ,dD.[Date]             AS TheDay
   FROM   
      dimPlayer AS P
   JOIN 
      dbo.factRevenue AS R ON P.playerKey = R.playerKey
   JOIN 
      dbo.vw_Date AS dD ON Dd.dateKey = R.dateKey
   WHERE    
      P.CustomerID   = 12345;

SELECT 
     A.TheDay               AS [Date]
    ,ISNULL(A.NetWin, 0)    AS NetWin
    ,SUM(B.NetWin)          AS CumulativeNetWin
FROM #temp AS A 
JOIN #temp AS B 
  ON A.TheDay >= B.TheDay
GROUP BY A.TheDay, ISNULL(A.NetWin, 0);
```

Comment: If it is giving the correct answer then materialize the CTE.  Create a temporary table rather than a CTE.   A CTE is just syntax so it is actually evaluated.   If you need a sample let me know.

Comment: Dont knnow who voted you down but I voted it up and approved the answer, thank you for the help!

Comment: Most likely that CTE is expensive and is evaluated many many times.

Answer (score 0):

Here https://stackoverflow.com/a/13744550/613130 it's suggested to use recursive CTE.

```
;WITH MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT 

           R.NetWinCURRENCYValue AS NetWin
          ,dD.[Date]             AS TheDay
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dD.[Date]) AS RN

    FROM   dimPlayer             AS P

        JOIN dbo.factRevenue     AS R   ON P.playerKey = R.playerKey
        JOIN dbo.vw_Date         AS dD  ON Dd.dateKey = R.dateKey

    WHERE    P.CustomerID   = 12345

)

, MyCTERec AS
(
    SELECT  C.TheDay               AS [Date]
           ,ISNULL(C.NetWin, 0)    AS NetWin
           ,ISNULL(C.NetWin, 0)    AS CumulativeNetWin
           ,C.RN

    FROM MyCTE AS C
    WHERE C.RN = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  C.TheDay               AS [Date]
           ,ISNULL(C.NetWin, 0)    AS NetWin
           ,P.CumulativeNetWin + ISNULL(C.NetWin, 0)    AS CumulativeNetWin
           ,C.RN

    FROM MyCTERec P
    INNER JOIN MyCTE AS C ON C.RN = P.RN + 1
)

SELECT * 
    FROM MyCTERec 
    ORDER BY RN
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Note that this query will work if you have 1 record == 1 day! If you have multiple records in a day, the results will be different from the other query.

Comment: In some cases there will be more than 1 record in a day, how would this be handled then?

Comment: @Etienne Then you can't use this solution (otherwise each record would have a different total... but perhaps it's ok... At 10.00 Cumulative is 10$, at 11.00 Cumulative is 20$...)

Answer (score 0):

As I said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sqlserver/13744550#13744550), if you want really fast calculation, put it into temporary table with sequential primary key and then calculate rolling total:

```
create table #Temp (
    ID bigint identity(1, 1) primary key,
    [Date] date,
    NetWin decimal(29, 10)
)

insert into #Temp ([Date], NetWin)
select
    dD.[Date],
    sum(R.NetWinCURRENCYValue) as NetWin,
from dbo.dimPlayer as P
    inner join dbo.factRevenue as R on P.playerKey = R.playerKey
    inner join dbo.vw_Date as dD on Dd.dateKey = R.dateKey
where P.CustomerID = 12345
group by dD.[Date]
order by dD.[Date]

;with cte as (
    select T.ID, T.[Date], T.NetWin, T.NetWin as CumulativeNetWin
    from #Temp as T
    where T.ID = 1

    union all

    select T.ID, T.[Date], T.NetWin, T.NetWin + C.CumulativeNetWin as CumulativeNetWin
from cte as C
    inner join #Temp as T on T.ID = C.ID + 1
)
select C.[Date], C.NetWin, C.CumulativeNetWin
from cte as C
order by C.[Date]
```

I assume that you could have duplicates dates in the input, but don't want duplicates in the output, so I grouped data before puting it into the table.